# var_dump - how to get the particular value from dump PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, var-dump

I know there is alot of information available in regards to PHP - var_dump my question is if I need to pick the particular information from the dump I am receiving from the API which is returning different array object....for example the below dump I need the information of realm under characterData Array how can I pick the that information and stored in String variable. Brief example of php code to explain my question will be highly appreciated...

```
  object(Character)[3]
   private 'name' => string 'XXXX' (length=6)
   private 'region' => string 'eu' (length=2)
   private 'realm' => string 'Defias Brotherhood' (length=18)
   private 'characterData' => 
   array (size=24)
  'lastModified' => float 1363345999000
  'name' => string 'Growar' (length=6)
  'realm' => string 'Defias Brotherhood' (length=18)
  'battlegroup' => string 'Rampage / Saccage' (length=17)
```

basically this information is coming from battlegroup api

```
    $armory = new BattlenetArmory('EU','Defias Brotherhood');
$armory->setLocale('ru_RU');

    // To reset back to default server locale
    $armory->setLocale(FALSE);
    //initialize the character to get the character object
    $character = $armory->getCharacter('XXXX');
```

Comment: The definition of the `Character` object will give you more information. Maybe it has a method that will allow you to get the `characterData`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a getter for the field `characterData`, you won't have access to it because it is a private property, unless you use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/ReflectionClass):

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass( 'Character');
$prop = $ref->getProperty( 'characterData');
$prop->setAccessible( true);
$array = $prop->getValue( $yourCharacterObject);
echo $array['realm'];
```

This can be tested with a simple class that mimics the OPs:

```
class Character {
    private $characterData;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->characterData['realm'] = 'Defias Brotherhood';
    }
}
```

Currently, others have the proposed this solution:

```
$yourCharacterObject = new Character();
// echo $yourCharacterObject->characterData['realm'];
```

Which results in:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property Character::$characterData in X on line 11

However, Reflection will be able to grab the private value and display it without error, as shown in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/txJDuY), which uses the above class and code to print the desired property value.

Comment: I am still getting an error 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Cannot access non-public member Character::characterData' in C:\wamp\www\apiX.php on line 63
( ! ) ReflectionException: Cannot access non-public member Character::characterData in C:\wamp\www\apiX.php on line 63

Comment: @ShoaibSuleman Make sure you call `$prop->setAccessible( true);`.

Comment: thanks...I manage to make it working can you please tell me how can I access the elements which are not public

Comment: actually now I am trying to access the object stats which is not public but it says the stats is invalid object

Comment: i mean its public and it complains that stats object does not exist

Answer (score 0):

`Character` is a class that you create instance from - for example:

```
$c = new Character();
```

since `characterData` is private you can't access it via `$c->characterData`

You need to use some public access function (like `getCharacterData`) or if you have access inside the object just changed it according to your needs

Comment: apologies but there is no getCharacterData

Comment: so use reflection like @nickb offers